# Kendo UI how to get grid properties using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

How do i get a Kendo UI grid orderBy property using jQuery data property?

For example in telerik UI , i can do something like

```
jQuery("#name").data("tGrid").orderBy
```

and this gives me the required result,i.e, the columns that the grid is currently being   ordered by. I am not able to find corresponding properties in Kendo
 .
Similarly I require groupBy and filterBy properties as well.

Answer (score 5):

To get group by, filter & sort properties, below is the way.. Reference [Kendo Grid API documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid)

```
var grid = $('#GridId').data('kendoGrid');
var grouping = grid.dataSource.group();
var filtering = grid.dataSource.filter();

var sorting = grid.dataSource.sort();
//here, sorting[0] will give you the field for which, sorting is done
```